# Html5 Video - Play/Pause video on screen click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, screen

,Hi,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <br> 
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div> 

<script> 
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause()
{ 
if (myVideo.paused) 
  myVideo.play(); 
else 
  myVideo.pause(); 
} 

function makeBig()
{ 
myVideo.width=560; 
} 

function makeSmall()
{ 
myVideo.width=320; 
} 

function makeNormal()
{ 
myVideo.width=420; 
} 
</script> 

<p>Video courtesy of <a href="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

I try to use html5 video from below website

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop

How can i play/pause video on video screen click ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: <video onclick="playPause()" id="video1" width="420"> solved the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click the poster image the HTML5 video plays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278262/click-the-poster-image-the-html5-video-plays)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply you can call the function video on click

```
<video id="video1" onClick="playPause();">
...
</video>
```

Comment: better to call this on video object itself otherwise clicking on anyother element will stop the video.

Answer (score 2):

## The shortest way

`onclick="this[this.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']()"`

## The right (but still short) way

...considering you already have your video in variable,
***you should generally use event listeners and not hard coded onX attributes...***
(even if you have callback!)

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
myVideo.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   this[this.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
});
```

---

PS: If you are wondering how the hack does the play/pause line work - it is based on the fact that in JavaScript, methods/object functions are basically callable properties of that object and also that in JavaScript, you can reference property directly `someObj.someProperty` but also through value or variable like `someObj["someProperty"]` , `var prop = "someProperty"; someObj[prop];`

... so a long equivalent of the one-liner would be

```
if (this.paused) {
   this.play();
} else {
   this.pause();
}
```