# what is the id/name of the play button that appears over videos on mobile devices?

Tags: asp.net, html, model-view-controller, mobile

what is the id/name of the play button that appears over videos on mobile devices?? I need to make a javascript that activates onclick of the play button, and I have no way to inspect elements on my iphone myself, and testing on chrome using iphone 6 view just autoplays video so the play button doesn't show up.
I am working on an mvc asp.net website and I need to activate javascript when the user clicks the play button on a mobile device thanks.

```
<div id="@carouselVideo">
                <div id="videoClick" class="videoBannerPosition" style="position:absolute; width:100%; ">
                    <video src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Video/")@item.selectFile" autoplay loop="" muted style="width:100%;"></video>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you using a `<video>` tag? You should show your existing video markup in your question.

Comment: can be anything mate. Depends on the player you are using to play the videos.

Comment: Seems like this could be a duplicate of [Html5 Video - Play/Pause video on screen click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014075/html5-video-play-pause-video-on-screen-click)

Comment: @mason i added the markup, all I need to know is if there is an id/name of the playbutton that shows up in the middle of the screen on a video on mobile. i already have my video play fine onscreen click of computer browsers so i don't think its the same as that other question you linked to. its just on mobile browser this play button shows up in the middle of the screen, the video plays fine if you click it, but my problem is its muted, i have javascript where if you click the video it unmutes and plays, but the playbutton doesnt activate the javascript so i need to know the name

Comment: so I ended up being able to use a mac to inspect elements of my iphone, but sadly the playbutton does not appear to display as an element.. so I am stuck with what to do.. if I remove the controls display from css then the play button goes away and im able to click the video. this works fine the video plays fullscreen and unmuted when i click but if i exit out of the video there is now no way to play the video again and clicking the video does nothing..