# using typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined' for video play detection

Tags: javascript, html, video, cross-browser

What I am trying to do is largely the same as [Click the poster image the HTML5 video plays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278262/click-the-poster-image-the-html5-video-plays). As you can see in the comments of the answer, it is noted that firefox (and other browsers) automatically play the video if you click on the poster anyway, while IE does not. To get around this issue, they say to use

```
typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined'
```

To determine whether or not to play the video. However, in the linked post, 
[How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser/9851769#9851769), there is heated discussion over browser detection being 'bad practice'. So, is there a way to force clicking on the poster to play the video regardless of the browser and without installtrigger. Beyond just playing the video, I noticed that for example Firefox has a play button centered in its video, and IE does not so I would like to display that button if it is not there.

Code:
HTML:

```
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-play big-play-button" ng-class='{inactive: play_btn_visible}' ng-click="play_video()"></div>
```

JS (note the all caps):

```
 scope.play_btn_visible = SHOULD THERE BE A CENTRAL PLAY BUTTON?;
        scope.play_video = function() {
            if (WILL THE VIDEO NOT BE AUTO-PLAYED ALREADY?) {
                elem[0].querySelector("video").play();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is primarily opinion based and makes this question "off topic"

Comment: Were I to modify the question to say "is there a way to force clicking on the poster to play the video regardless of the browser and not using installtrigger". And left out the bit about it being an acceptable practice. Then it is simply asking if there is another way, not if it is a better way

Comment: You would be better off adding your code, and your problem then letting someone answer it. Take out the "better ways" to do things vocab.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith can you recheck the question

Comment: Yes, I retracted my close vote. plus one.